# Google Custom Login Button

Tags: javascript

Hello I am using latest Google Identity Services library (https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/migration) for updating Login functionality in my web application.
No issue with library and everything is working fine.

The problem is that I am using custom login button to match with our website design and current google service is not allowing me to customize the default button.

Below is the trick which i am currently trying to apply but no luck. The trick is like clicking on dummy button google login popup should get open.

So I added one custom button and hided default google button.
So now 2 buttons on the screen. One is dummy and one is google one but not visible.
On clicking on custom button i am trying to trigger click event of google login. But it is not working. I used many times this trick on other services and it was working there.

I hope I am able to explain my problem.

Any help is very much appreciate.

Comment: consider amending your question and including a small section of code to help others identify what is going wrong to assist in providing you an answer.